# Why doesn't Aptana allow creating a new PHP project by cloning git repository

Tags: git, aptana, git-clone

I'm working with Aptana 3 to build a PHP-based web app using phpfog. I want to create a new project in Aptana by cloning my git repository from phpfog but this is not an option for a 'php project.' Aptana only gives this option for 'Rails' and 'Ruby' projects. Does anyone know why?

I'm attempting to follow instructions in this video: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=21nq-xLvQtM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the Ruby project first to clone from the git repository and then change the nature by right-clicking on the project and selecting Properties > Project Natures.

Answer (score 3):

You could also File > Import > Git to clone the project and then also right-click on the project and selecting Properties > Project natures. Either way, there's now a feature request for that too: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-2923